# Build.Gradle (Module App ) unknown property

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have encountered this problem while syn of Gradle
[image]

This is the Code of build.gradle(Module app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ahmedchtn.smartschool"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //RecyclerView


    //retrofit,gson

    //glide
    compile
    'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'compile
    'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'compile
    'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'compile
    'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'compile
    'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have tried to deleted some lines of compile but I did not arrive to resolve the problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few typos in your file:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

You should not have line break after `compile`.

Typical structure of `dependencies` block is:

```
dependencies {
    // production
    compile 'group:name:version'

    // for local tests
    testCompile 'group:name:version'

    // for tests on device / emulator
    androidTestCompile 'group:name:version'
}
```

If you really want to have line break (I don't even know why) you have to explicitly add parentheses around dependency definition:

```
compile (
    'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this.

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```